# UIPinchGestureRecognizer scaling a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to use a pinch gesture to scale a collection view only in the y direction. I'm setting the scale correctly (sufficiently), but having trouble keeping the pinched area of the collection view centered.

I've seen many examples of adjusting the translation to keep the pinched content centered, but not to keep a collection view/scroll view content offset centered. Is there something I'm missing here?

I have a sample project which demonstrates it at https://github.com/nickbolton/ScaledCollectionView.

Can anyone offer any suggestions/recommendations/approaches?  I'm just not sure where to go with this.

Thanks!